# Android Fragment Handling for Smart Phone and Tablet?

Tags: android

I need to implement Fragmentation concept in my android sample app. If the device is smart phone then when i click on buton it should display the result in another window else if it is tablet then it should display the result in same window. But i don't know how to do it. I got some references code but it works for tablet not for smart phone. when i try to run that same project then it's giving the force close error. So any one have an idea please help me.

Any advise is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would highly recommend [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) tutorial, it describes the concept perfectly and provides a very clear and simple example of implementing Fragments in your application. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Using this tutorial i finished my task. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Am also trying to do for tablets and mobile.Any sample project for dynamically change the fragment list based on buttonclick.